# Counting Characters in a varible python

Tags: python, variables

i am trying to create a program to print a line of text a certain amount of times, i want to limit the amount of letters in the first text entry and i cant figure out how.

code:

```
# Hello World Script 2.0

import random
**------------------------------------------------
#i want to limit the amount of characters, how?
------------------------------------------------**
print("What do you want to be printed?(Max 20 Characters)")
var0 = input("> ")

print("Please enter the amount of times you want that printed(max 100000)")
print('Or enter "R" for a random number')
var2 = input("> ")

if int(var2) > 100000:
    print("That number is too high, please restart the proram and enter something smaller.")
    exit()

if var2 == "r":
    var2 = random.randint(1,100000)


var1 = var0 * int(var2)
print(var1, var2)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please provide the sample input string and your desired output string. What you want is not clear in your question

Comment: I want the user to input text, I want that to be a maximum of 20 characters. I want to know how to get python to count those characters and print "That is too long"

Comment: You need `len()` for that. Your code will be like: `if len(your_string) > 20: print "Too Long"`

Comment: Ok thanks, I am just learning python

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of the string with the function len().

```
import random
**------------------------------------------------
#i want to limit the amount of characters, how?
------------------------------------------------**
print("What do you want to be printed?(Max 20 Characters)")
var0 = input("> ")

if len(var0) > 20:
   print("That is too long")
   exit()

print("Please enter the amount of times you want that printed(max 100000)")
print('Or enter "R" for a random number')
var2 = input("> ")

if int(var2) > 100000:
    print("That number is too high, please restart the proram and enter something smaller.")
    exit()

if var2 == "r":
    var2 = random.randint(1,100000)


var1 = var0 * int(var2)
print(var1, var2)
```

Comment: If the answer has been useful, please confirm it, in order that other users can consider this solution as a valid solution.